# how do i use socket.send method in this program?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have written this code to search for a string from a file. Since this program cannot be used for multiple clients, i was asked to make it more robust by using socket. I want to know where and how socket could be used in this program.. I'm still learning about sockets.. Couldn't exactly figure out where and how exactly it could be used.. Could someone just help me with it? This is my program..

class Program
    {

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (File.Exists("C://myfile2.txt"))
        {
            var text = File.ReadAllText("C://myfile2.txt");


            foreach (var word in new[] { "and", "so", "not", "c", "to", "by", "has", "do", "behavior", "dance", "france", "ok","that", "please","hello","system","possible","impossible","absolutely","sachin","bradman","schumacher","http","console","application" })
            {
                var w = word;

                new Thread(() => Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", w, text.Contains(w) ? "Present" : "Not Present")).Start();
            }

        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("File Does not exist");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure? Sockets seem a bizarre way to go for this.

Comment: @AdamKing Yes Adam. I was asked to do it that way. I'm not very sure about why would it be bizarre, since i'm still learning about this. But i have to listen to the boss. :) And thank u so much Adam. :)

Comment: How would you envisage the software working? Do the problems get sent from multiple clients or do you distribute the problem to multiple clients. I am struggling to see which way around from your question.

Comment: @AdamKing Basically, this particular program is used to search for strings from files or emails. So i was asked to used sockets because the number of requests and clients might exceed more than 10.

Comment: Sounds like a job for WCf, net.tcp. google for that.

Comment: You only have to listen to your boss if he knows more about the subject than you. But on-topic, what kind of clients are you talking about? Sockets are used to communicate between programs.

Comment: @AdamKing The problems get sent from multiple clients..

Comment: @hcb Well said. Thats exactly my situation. :) I have to listen to him since he does know better than me, atleast till i learn about this completely. Just give me a min, i'll let u know what kind of clients.

Comment: @hcb I was asked to program this for one client for now. He says, if there's a request from the client side to search for anything (in this case, a particular string) it should return the value. And i'm supposed to write the program for server side. Thanks alot hcb.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Allright, You should create a client server app with a tcp connection. [Here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server) is a tutorial how that works.